# Java - Issue with static ArrayList with a recursive call

Tags: java, arraylist, heap

I have written the following program to maxify a heap :

```
package heap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeapMaxify 
{
    public static List<Integer> inp;
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
        inp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner inpObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        inp.add(inpObj.nextInt());
        for(int i=1;i<=inp.get(0);i++)
            inp.add(inpObj.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Current heap follows :");
        int elemInLine = 1;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=inp.get(0);i++)
        {
            System.out.print(inp.get(i)+"\t");
            count++;
            if(count==elemInLine)
            {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
                elemInLine *= 2;
            }
        }
        maxifyHeap(inp,1);
        System.out.println("Maxified heap follows :");
        elemInLine = 1;
        count = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=inp.get(0);i++)
        {
            System.out.print(inp.get(i)+"\t");
            count++;
            if(count==elemInLine)
            {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
                elemInLine *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void maxifyHeap(List<Integer> inp, int curIndex)
    {
        int leftIndex = 2*curIndex;
        int rightIndex = (2*curIndex)+1;
        int largestIndex=0;
        int temp;
        if(leftIndex<=inp.get(0)&&inp.get(leftIndex)>inp.get(curIndex))
            largestIndex = leftIndex;
        else
            largestIndex = curIndex;
        if(rightIndex<=inp.get(0)&&inp.get(rightIndex)>inp.get(largestIndex))
            largestIndex = rightIndex;
        if(largestIndex!=curIndex)
        {
            temp = inp.get(largestIndex);
            inp.set(largestIndex, inp.get(curIndex));
            inp.set(curIndex, temp);
            maxifyHeap(inp, largestIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the input ArrayList does not change at all.
I'm making some mistake with understanding the scope of changes applied to the ArrayList but I can't seem to make it out.

Output:

```
10
16
4
10
14
7
9
3
2
8
1
Current heap follows :
16  
4   10  
14  7   9   3   
2   8   1   Maxified heap follows :
16  
4   10  
14  7   9   3   
2   8   1
```

Comment: For one thing, it's not clear why you use a static variable at all. You've already got a parameter accepting the variable, so you can just make `inp` a local variable in `main` as well. I would also *not* just use the first element as the size; a list already knows its size. You should separate out those concepts. But when I ran your code, the list *did* change... please show an example where it doesn't. (Ideally, just hard-code the input - it'll make it easier for us to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what is the best way to return an arraylist after a recursive method is done with the processing?

Comment: Updated the question with the output

Comment: Right - try with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead. Then you'll see a difference. So it's not a matter of the scope or being unable to modify the list - it's a matter of your `maxifyHeap` method not being correct.

Comment: aah! got it. Thanks for your inputs. I'll give my code another look.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cMRFXD6a try this way

Comment: Thanks Susheel but adding braces to single line braces will not cause any difference. There was a logical problem in my code and I figured it out.
Thanks everyone for their time.